# Relationship between eigenvalues of matrix squared

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be symmetric positive definite. Suppose $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^T A $. Then we know $\lambda(A^T A ) = \lambda(A^2 )$

Does it follow that $\lambda(A^2) = [\lambda(A)]^2 $ ?

Comment: symmetric means $A^T = A$

Comment: what does $[\cdot]$ means?

Comment: just $ \lambda(A) \times \lambda(A) $

Comment: The notation is somewhat ambiguous: Do you mean that $\lambda(B)$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of $B$ for all (square) matrices $B$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. The proof is an easy application of the spectral theorem (and does not have much to do with $A^T A$).

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, then $A^TA = A^2$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** If $A=U\Lambda U^T$ where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues and $U$ is the orthonormal matrix of eigenvectors, then $A^2=U\Lambda^2 U^T$ (can you prove this?). Let $\lambda_{max}(.)$ denote the largest eigenvalue. Thus $\lambda_{max}(A)=\lambda_{max}(\Lambda)$. Also, $\lambda_{max}(A^2)=\lambda_{max}(\Lambda^2)$. Now can you think of any situation where $\lambda_{max}(\Lambda^2)\leq\lambda_{max}(\Lambda)^2$ for any diagonal matrix $\Lambda$.